# Geokit query with multiple models involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

My database structure consists of Store, Book, BookStore and Address as below.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_stores
  has_many :books, :through => :book_stores

  has_many :addresses
  acts_as_mappable :through => :addresses
end  

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  acts_as_mappable
end  

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_stores
  has_many :stores, :through => :book_stores
end  

# Join table for many to many relationship between books and stores
class BookStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Now given a book isbn (which is in the Book model) and a store, I need to find other stores within 5 miles that have that book.

I have looked around but not quite sure how to bring in the Book and BookStore models with my GeoKit query on something like Store.within(5, :origin => @storeaddr).

I am on Rails 3.0.5 and using gem 'geokit-rails3'

Appreciate any thoughts/pointers.

-S

Comment: Figured it out - Store.joins(:books, :addresses).where("books.isbn = '9780316346627'").within(5, :origin => @addr)